# Anyway to programmatically add default fields to a layout?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, custom-field

So I've been building my plugin to import product listings directly from Salesforce. So far I've been making progress. However, I've approached another roadblock and I was wondering how I would approach this issue. I want to write some code to add default fields into my product layout (e.g.- Body richtext, Image Asset field),

Someone showed me an example of this function that adds default content for a ProductType

```
/**
 * @throws \Craft\Exception
 * @throws \Exception
 */
private function defaultProductTypes()
{
    $productType = new Commerce_ProductTypeModel;
    $productType->name = 'Clothing';
    $productType->handle = 'clothing';
    $productType->hasDimensions = true;
    $productType->hasUrls = true;
    $productType->hasVariants = false;
    $productType->hasVariantTitleField = false;
    $productType->titleFormat = "{product.title}";
    $productType->template = 'shop/products/_product';

    $fieldLayout = FieldLayoutModel::populateModel(['type' => 'Commerce_Product']);
    \Craft\craft()->fields->saveLayout($fieldLayout);
    $productType->asa('productFieldLayout')->setFieldLayout($fieldLayout);

    $variantFieldLayout = FieldLayoutModel::populateModel(['type' => 'Commerce_Variant']);
    \Craft\craft()->fields->saveLayout($variantFieldLayout);
    $productType->asa('variantFieldLayout')->setFieldLayout($variantFieldLayout);

    \Craft\craft()->commerce_productTypes->saveProductType($productType);

    $productTypeLocales = \Craft\craft()->i18n->getSiteLocaleIds();

    foreach ($productTypeLocales as $locale) {
        \Craft\craft()->db->createCommand()->insert('commerce_producttypes_i18n', [
            'productTypeId' => $productType->id,
            'locale' => $locale,
            'urlFormat' => 'shop/products/{slug}'
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've tried to read through to see where I could include extra fields, but I'm a bit lost on where to start. Can anyone provide some insight or approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of perusing, I managed to find a working solution to this issue.  I threw this implementation from InstallService located in `craft/app/services`.

I realized that CommerceProduct and Variant Field Layouts were set into the Commerce Product Type Model via `setFieldLayout()` function, therefore all I would need to do is create a new Field Layout with the fields that I required and set them into `defaultProductTypes()`.

```
    //Write this code in between CommerceProductFieldLayout and Variant type field Layout

    //Any custom fields for your products go here.
    //Format: $yourFieldName = FieldsVariable::getFieldByHandle("Your field's 
handle");
    $bodyField = FieldsVariable::getFieldByHandle('body');
    $tagsField= FieldsVariable::getFieldByHandle('tags');

    //Assemble a new layout that contains the fields you need.
    $infoLayout = craft()->fields->assembleLayout(
        array(
            'Content' => array($bodyField->id, $tagsField->id) //Add fields into this array to display your plugins. (e.g. - $YourFieldVariable->id)
        ),
        array($bodyField->id) //Add any required fields here.
    );

    // Save Layout into specified product type.
    $productType->setFieldLayout($infoLayout);
```